# Error al obtener el valor de un ComboBox en Java

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un programa, quiero que al presionar un botón me imprima el valor seleccionado de un `JComboBox`, pero  solo me recoge el primer valor del `ComboBox` aunque seleccione uno diferente.

```
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
        try{
            if(evt.getSource()==convertir){
                String seleccion = p.codeP.getSelectedItem().toString();
                //p.codeP es el ComboBox que está en otra clase

                System.out.println(seleccion);
                }
        } catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("Error -> "+e);
            }
    }
```

estas son las propiedades del JComboBox

```
    public void JComboBoxProperties(){
        String [] unidades = {"Seleccionar","Octal", "Hexadecimal", "Binario", "Decimal"};
        JComboBox<String> codeP = new JComboBox<>(unidades);
        codeP.setBounds(20, 60, 100, 20);
        codeP.setSelectedItem("Seleccionar");
        codeP.setVisible(true); //this.add(codeP);
    }
```

Comment: Me parece que el problema principal puede ser este if:  if(evt.getSource()==convertir){ , revisa mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con:

```
String seleccion = String.valueOf(JComboBox.getSelectedItem());
```

Respuesta sacada de una pregunta parecida: [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962416/preferred-way-of-getting-the-selected-item-of-a-jcombobox/39768815)

Comment: ya apliqué el método, pero me presenta lo mismo, solo me imprime la palabra "seleccionar" que es la primera, es como si no detectara que selecciono otro valor de la lista

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes realizar de esta forma:

```
String seleccion = codeP.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

o mediante:

```
String seleccion = String.valueOf(codeP.getSelectedItem());
```

Debe funcionar pero también elimina este `if`, pero si en verdad lo necesitas únicamente funcionaría si el valor de `convertir` es "comboBoxChanged" de esta forma:

```
     if(evt.getActionCommand() == convertir){
        System.out.println(codeP.getSelectedItem().toString());
        String seleccion = String.valueOf(codeP.getSelectedItem());// codeP.getSelectedItem().toString();
        System.out.println("seleccion: " +seleccion );
     }
```

Revisa el código:

```
   // Creacion del JComboBox y añadir los items.
   String [] unidades = {"Seleccionar","Octal", "Hexadecimal", "Binario", "Decimal"};
   JComboBox<String> codeP = new JComboBox<>(unidades);
   codeP.setBounds(20, 60, 100, 20);
   codeP.setSelectedItem("Seleccionar");
   codeP.setVisible(true); //this.add(codeP);


   //Acción a realizar cuando el JComboBox cambia de item seleccionado.
   codeP.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                             
                       // if(evt.getSource()==convertir){                               
                           String seleccion = codeP.getSelectedItem().toString();
                           System.out.println(seleccion);
                       // }
    }                                                
});
```